# Unity3D web player with Chrome Native Client?

Tags: google-chrome

After reading up on various websites, I am rather confused about the ability to run Unity3D (http://unity3d.com/) web player in Native Client.

I am not sure whether it is the Unity 3D engine itself which can run in Native Client or Unity 3D Web Player.

I was hoping to find information on running the Unity 3D Web Player in Native Client in Chrome, because there are certain sites that require the Web Player, but that is available only for Windows or Mac.

Has anybody got more information on this or tried it themselves? One of the sites whose content I want to access is http://intoscience.com/.

Answer (score 1):

What I have seen is that Unity Apps can be compiled with the NaCl (Native Client) and then can run without the plugin needed. However, this does not mean that any Unity app can run in Chrome without the plugin, thus killing most of the possibilities for Ubuntu D:

Sorry about the late reply, I was researching this same thing when I came across this question without any answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, it can run Web Applications made which require Unity 3D web player plugin without actually having it.

Sorry if I counfused you, but I suck at making sentences.